# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rapidapi

I've been working on a React project along with fetching Data from rapidAPI.
But whenever I rum my project I've been getting this error again and again.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')
Homepage
src/components/Homepage.jsx:23
  20 | <>
  21 |   <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
  22 |   <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
> 23 |     <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
     | ^  24 |     <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats.totalExchanges)} /></Col>
  25 |     <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap:" value={`$${millify(globalStats.totalMarketCap)}`} /></Col>
  26 |     <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats.total24hVolume)}`} /></Col>
```

Here are the files that I've been looking in to debug.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout, Typography, Space } from 'antd';

import { Exchanges, Homepage, News, Cryptocurrencies, CryptoDetails, Navbar } from './components';
import './App.css';

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="navbar">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
    <div className="main">
      <Layout>
        <div className="routes">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Homepage />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/exchanges">
              <Exchanges />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/cryptocurrencies">
              <Cryptocurrencies />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/crypto/:coinId">
              <CryptoDetails />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/news">
              <News />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Layout>
      <div className="footer">
        <Typography.Title level={5} style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>Copyright © 2021
          <Link to="/">
            Cryptoverse Inc.
          </Link> <br />
          All Rights Reserved.
        </Typography.Title>
        <Space>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
          <Link to="/news">News</Link>
        </Space>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**Homepage.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import millify from 'millify';
import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/cryptoApi';
import Cryptocurrencies from './Cryptocurrencies';
import News from './News';
import Loader from './Loader';

const { Title } = Typography;

const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery(10);
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;

  if (isFetching) return <Loader />;

  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats.totalExchanges)} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap:" value={`$${millify(globalStats.totalMarketCap)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats.total24hVolume)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Markets" value={millify(globalStats.totalMarkets)} /></Col>
      </Row>
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Top 10 Cryptos In The World</Title>
        <Title level={3} className="show-more"><Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <Cryptocurrencies simplified />
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Latest Crypto News</Title>
        <Title level={3}><Link to="/news">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <News simplified />
    </>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

**services/cryptoApi.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': '268c978691mshf443e1a9132dfdep1f3fe3jsn953b6183c440',
};

const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'cryptoApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getCryptos: builder.query({
        query: (count) => createRequest(`/coins/?limit=${count}`),
      }),
      getExchanges: builder.query({
        query: () => createRequest('/exchanges'),
      }),
      getCryptoDetails: builder.query({
        query: (coinId) => createRequest(`/coin/${coinId}`),
      }),
      getCryptoHistory: builder.query({
        query: ({ coinId, timeperiod }) => createRequest(`coin/${coinId}/history/${timeperiod}`),
      }),
    }),
  });

export const {
    useGetCryptosQuery,
    useGetCryptoDetailsQuery,
    useGetCryptoHistoryQuery,
    useGetExchangesQuery,
} = cryptoApi;
```

I've tried a lot but the situation continues.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

when you are passing `value` to your `<Col />` tag in `src/components/Homepage.jsx:23` , you passed `globalStats.total`

but when the application arrives at this line, `globalStats` is still empty.
you should handle what to do in this situation

for example, you can check `null condition` when you are reading it like this :

```
value={globalStats?.total}
```

or maybe you want to declare a default value when you are declaring your main variable like this :

```
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats ?? {}
  // globalStats will be an empty object if your data?.data?.stats be empty
```

or maybe you want to show loading if it was empty like this :

```
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;
  if (isFetching || !globalStats) return <Loader />;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is gonna help but have you tried rendering only when there is globalStats?
example :

```
 return (
    <>
{globalstats?  <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats.totalExchanges)} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap:" value={`$${millify(globalStats.totalMarketCap)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats.total24hVolume)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Markets" value={millify(globalStats.totalMarkets)} /></Col>
      </Row>
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Top 10 Cryptos In The World</Title>
        <Title level={3} className="show-more"><Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <Cryptocurrencies simplified />
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Latest Crypto News</Title>
        <Title level={3}><Link to="/news">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <News simplified />
</> : <> "" </> }
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

`globalStats` is undefined here; at the time of this error. You can use the optional chaining operator `?.` (`value={globalStats?.total}`):

```
<Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats?.total} /></Col>
```

or you can return `null` when `globalStats` is not defined:

```
if (!globalStats) return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the `Homepage.jsx` when you call `globalStats` - it's `undefined`.

You can either check if the object exists, using the question mark:

```
<Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats?.total} />
```

or you can add a check outside of the fragment, to display the content only if  `globalStats` exists:

```
return globalStats ? (<><Title>Global Crypto Stats</Title><>the rest...</></>) : null;
```